# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have a problem regarding adapter in fragment. It throws a typo shown below.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
```

Here is the code snippet.

```
SongDetailFragment fragment =
                        SongDetailFragment.newInstance(selectedSong);
                AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext().getApplicationContext();
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.song_detail_container, fragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: in which class is this code written?

Comment: did you use this code in your activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Fragment use:

```
AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
```

instead of:

```
AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext().getApplicationContext();
```