# trying to open fragment from fragment java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I use this code in recyclerViewAdapter. I need to open new fragment from fragment.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();


        CarDetailFragment carDetailFragment = new CarDetailFragment();
        FragmentManager  fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentCar, carDetailFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: YourAppCompatActivityName rather than AppCompatActivity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57962537/java-lang-classcastexception-android-app-application-cannot-be-cast-to-androidx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a public static context variable in your Fragment and assign getActivity to it and then use this variable in Adapter to your getSupportFragmentManager.

```
public static Context context; //declare the variable in your Fragment

context=getActivity;// assign it in your Fragment before calling Adapter
```

Then in Adapter use it like this

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager= ((AppCompatActivity) YourFragmentName.context).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

**EDIT**

As static context variable could cause memory leak so you can use this

```
    // while calling the adapter pass getActivity as context
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity, /* other variables */);
```

Then in Adapter use it like this

```
    private Context context;
    public MyAdapter(Context context, /* Other part */ ) {
        this.context = context;
        //other part
      }


   FragmentManager fragmentManager= ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Comment: I have this: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity, but i write public void onClick(View view)  inside the recycleView Adapter

Comment: Please look at the edit that I have added if it helps and let me know if it works or not

Comment: @МихаилБит-Савва please check the new edit and let me know how it works

Comment: it works, one more question: app show me new fragment but don`t hide previous?

Comment: @МихаилБит-Савва In that case you try this `FragmentToHide f = new FragmentToHide(); fragmentTransaction.hide(f); fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentCar, carDetailFragment);`. Actually hide and add is equivalent to replace

Comment: Don't store activity context in static variables, it's a common cause of memory leaks ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908039/android-static-fields-and-memory-leaks), [2](https://blog.mindorks.com/detecting-and-fixing-memory-leaks-in-android), [3](https://medium.com/swlh/context-and-memory-leaks-in-android-82a39ed33002)).

Comment: @EugenPechanec then we can pass the activity content to the required adapter while calling it. But I think it helped the author as a solution to his question and so there was no good reason for downvoting this answer rather you could just edit the answer

Comment: Why do you think _I_ downvoted your answer? That's not a very nice assumption, I'm just trying to help. That being said, one half of your answer promotes a bad practice (static context), the other half (`AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity)view.getContext().getApplicationContext();`) is wrong (you can't cast `Application` to `Activity`). I believe this qualifies a downvote. I already explained my point of view in another answer.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Yes,  I had made that mistake in a hurry but it was of no use, so I had removed it. I had also done a edit to avoid memory leak hope now there is no issue and you may like it

Comment: Context doesn't have fragment manager. Please, focus, there's no hurry. Take the time you need to make good answer. Test your code, improve formatting...

Comment: Thanks for pointing the mistake. I just forgot to add `(AppCompatActivity) `

Comment: If you know the context is actually an activity and you cast it to activity, why bother passing `Context`? Why not just pass the activity as `Activity`?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below code and you can direct `getContext()` in a fragment and cast it to your activity of the current fragment.

```
Context context= getContext();
CarDetailFragment carDetailFragment = new CarDetailFragment();
FragmentManager  fragmentManager = ((YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentCar, carDetailFragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: not working "java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.bacon.expandablelistview.activity.MainActivity"

Comment: `getApplicationContext();` instead of `getContext();` and check it

Comment: otherwise ypu can call directly `getActivity()` instead of `((YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME) context)`

Comment: Context context= getContext(); i cant call this and this Context context= getApplicationContext();

Comment: `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();` direct write loike this

Answer (score 0):

Please take the reference from below code ..

```
public class NewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewAdapter.<Your-View-Holder-Name>> {
    private FragmentActivity activity;

    public ImageAdapter(FragmentActivity mActivity){
        activity = mActivity;

    }
```

Change your getActivity() to activity as mentioned below..

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        FragmentManager  fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); 
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentCar, carDetailFragment); 
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

When you make instance of Adapter class in Activity please use following syntax..

```
 mAdapter = new NewAdapter(MainActivityHomePage.this);
```

Comment: pass your activity reference to adapter and use this reference to call getSupportFragmentManager

Comment: how can i pass it, can you explain, please

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your `RecyclerView` adapter holds a reference to application context and you're using that to create views. The views then hold the context you used to create them, so when you ask them to `getContext()` they're going to give you the application instead of the <s>activity</s> themed context.

What to keep in mind:

1. `Activity` extends `Context`, so forget about `getBaseContext()`.
2. When working with views, you want a *themed context*. If you're inside a `View` use `getContext()`. If you're inside an `Activity` use `this`. If you're inside `Fragment` use `getContext()`. Forget about `getApplicationContext()` when working with views.
3. Your adapter doesn't need `Context` in constructor. The only place you need a context is when creating views and you can get the right `Context` from the `RecyclerView` which is going to display the items.

   ```
   @Override 
   public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       // parent is the RecyclerView.
       Context context = parent.getContext();
       // TODO Inflate your view and return view holder.
   }
   ```

---

Even if you follow all this you don't get a guarantee that `View.getContext()` will get you an `Activity`. It could be a `ContextThemeWrapper`.

Start thinking about the app architecture. The adapter probably shouldn't know anything about activities or fragments or fragment transactions. The adapter should take data and turn them into views. In the other direction it should take clicks from user and notify *some* listener. The adapter should take a `onClickListener` constructor parameter, which you prepared inside the activity (which knows how to do fragment transactions).